# Get 3D Chemical Structures - Python Automation

Tags: javascript, python, chemistry, pymol, cheminformatics

I am working in python and i want to get a series of 3D images for the molecules I'm using.

I have .mol files stored in my folder and for each of them I would like to obtain a 3D render of its 'stick' representation.
With py3Dmol i can get a 3D structure of the molecule, but i can only view it and it is not stored anywhere in python. Here a source (from the author of the package) explaining why images cannot be saved

- https://github.com/3dmol/3Dmol.js/issues/380

Do you have any suggestion on how to do automatize the creation of 3D structure images for a set of molecule?

Comment: Use pymol to load your mol pymol.cmd.load( filename.mol , str(filename) , manipulate it and use cmd.png( .... ) to save it as png dont forget to use the ray parameter to make it look nice.   A for loop  on your molecule folder should be enough. You could rotate the molecule to save different views of it. I guess in any case you'll have to inspect them one by one the get the right projection though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK , here my attempt, please have a look at [Multiple PyMOL Instances in Python Script](https://www.mail-archive.com/pymol-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg14944.html) and [Launching From a Script](https://pymolwiki.org/index.php/Launching_From_a_Script) that explains how this works:

```
"""
Yes it's possible to have independent instances. The API has actually been 
around for a long time. For some reason it was never widely adopted and thus is 
not very thoroughly tested. Please report any bugs you encounter.

Example:
"""
import pymol2
p = pymol2.PyMOL()
p.start()
p.cmd.fragment('ala')
p.cmd.show_as('sticks')
p.cmd.zoom()
p.cmd.png('/tmp/ala.png', 1000, 800, dpi=150, ray=1)
p.stop()
```

Code :

```
import pymol2

import os

work_dir = "." 

file_folders = os.listdir(work_dir)  


mol_files = [item for item in file_folders if os.path.isfile(item) and   item.rsplit('.')[1] == 'mol']

print(mol_files)


for mol_file in mol_files:
    

    p = pymol2.PyMOL()
    
    p.start()
    
    mol_name = mol_file.rsplit('.')[0]
    
    print(mol_file.rsplit('.')[0])
    
    try :
     
        p.cmd.load(mol_file , mol_name)
    
        p.cmd.hide(representation = 'sticks' , selection = mol_name)
        
        p.cmd.show(representation = 'lines' , selection = mol_name)
        
        p.cmd.do('set ray_opaque_background, 0')
        ## or to get black background instead of transparent
        #p.cmd.bg_color(color="black")
        #p.cmd.do('set ray_opaque_background, 1')
        
        p.cmd.orient(mol_name)
        
        p.cmd.png(mol_name+'.png' , dpi = 400, width = 5000, ray = 1)
        
        p.cmd.remove(mol_name)
        
        p.stop()
        
    except :
        
        print('\nError ----> something is wrong with ', mol_name+'.mol file \n')
    
print('finished ...............................')
```

Note that the molecules are oriented on the screen by `pymol.cm.orient()` that as per the wiki:

> orient aligns the principal components of the atoms in the selection with the XYZ axes. T

AS an example here the pic for GLC from [Chemical Components in the PDB GLC : Summary](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/pdbe-srv/pdbechem/chemicalCompound/show/GLC)

[image: pic]

Answer (score 0):

I think You can use the Python PIL library to capture the Py3Dmol view as an image.

May be try this

```
from rdkit import Chem
from rdkit.Chem import AllChem
import py3Dmol
from PIL import Image
import os

def read_mol_from_file(file_path):
    mol = Chem.MolFromMolFile(file_path)
    return mol

def generate_3D_coordinates(mol):
    AllChem.EmbedMolecule(mol, randomSeed=42)

def render_to_png(mol, filename):
    block = Chem.MolToMolBlock(mol)
    viewer = py3Dmol.view(width=300, height=300)
    viewer.addModel(block, "sdf")
    viewer.setStyle({'stick': {}})
    viewer.zoomTo()
    viewer.show()
    # Capture the view as an image (this part needs manual intervention)
    # An automated screenshot capturing method can be used here

# Directory containing your .mol files
mol_dir = "./molecules"

for mol_file in os.listdir(mol_dir):
    if mol_file.endswith('.mol'):
        mol_path = os.path.join(mol_dir, mol_file)
        mol = read_mol_from_file(mol_path)
        
        if not mol.GetNumConformers():  # Check if 3D coordinates exist
            generate_3D_coordinates(mol)
        
        output_file = f"{mol_file.split('.')[0]}.png"
        render_to_png(mol, output_file)
```